# Error creating flutter project on Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[Flutter create error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2cCu.png)

Hello, everyone, I'm on Windows using VS Code to discover Flutter. I have tried to open (create) a new project on Vs Code used terminal to do that but somehow i couldn't. The error is following: Cannot create a project within the Flutter SDK. Target directory
`C:\src\Flutter\flutter\projects\hello_world\study` is within the Flutter SDK at
`C:\src\Flutter\flutter`.

Btw in my flutter folder should i create a projects folder?

Comment: What about the error seems unclear to you? It seems to state clearly that you cannot do that, because your project would end up being within the Flutter SDK folder, which Flutter clearly disallows. Have you tried starting the project in some other, unrelated folder, e.g. in Documents?

Comment: It does but i tought i could create a projects folder in flutter folder. Should i delete it and create on C:\src\Projects ? and then i can store all language projects in that foler? I'm new to computer stuff

Comment: You can create a project wherever Flutter lets you. It does NOT let you create it within its own source folder, as it says. It should be fine with the folder anywhere else you make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are trying to create a directory inside the Flutter SDK, as it says. Which means it is assuming that you are trying to modify (add/delete) something in the Flutter original code.

Instead, you can create a directory somewhere else - maybe out of `C:` or if you want it in `C:` do it somewhere here `C:\src\yourDirectory`.

Comment: Tranks I got it. One more thing: if im using terminal to do that should be changing directory or can i spesify directory like flutter dir create?

Comment: Didn't get you..but, I guess, you can give it a try for yourself.. kindly, upvote the answer, if it is relevant and also accept the answer if it solves your issue :)